# How to animate css binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have this binding:

```
data-bind="css: imageClass"
```

viewmodel:

```
imageClass: ko.observable("bg-image0")
```

css:

```
.bg-image0 {background-image:url(/content/images/image0.jpg)

.bg-image1 {background-image:url(/content/images/image1.jpg)

.bg-image2 {background-image:url(/content/images/image2.jpg)
```

I would like the class to change every 3 seconds, so it shows image 0,1,2, 0,1,2 etc.

How do I do that?

Comment: I assume it's because this reads more like a specification than an attempt at solving it before getting stuck somewhere, so falls under the "lack of research" downvote tooltip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple timer with a variable to update the observable is all that's needed:

```
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    counter++;
    if (counter === 3)
        counter = 0;
    //assume your viewmodel is "vm":
    vm.imageClass('bg-image' + counter);
}, 3000);
```